# Unable to create Apple Developer certificate request using keychain access tool

Tags: iphone, certificate, request, provisioning, keychain

I'm creating a new CSR (Certificate Signing Request) using the Keychain Access tool:

- Certificate Assistant -> Request a certificate from a certificate authority...
- In the certificate information I fill in my email address and name,
  selecting the "Save to disk" option.
- I save the CSR to the desktop
- The wizard completes successfully, but no file is saved to disk!

I've done this before, but this time it just isn't working. I tried restarting the
Keychain tool, restarting the computer, no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried on another Mac and it worked fine there. I also noticed that on the Mac that worked, the certificate information dialog has a "Let me specify key pair information" checkbox. This checkbox doesn't show in the Mac where it fails...

Answer (score 10):

You have an existing private key selected in the main window of Keychain Access.  That is also why it says "Request a certificate from a certificate authority *using {some id}"* in the menu.  Deselect the private key by selecting something else, and then it will work.  Apple if you're reading this, you need an error message at the end of the sequence described above.

Comment: Why isn't this accepted answer? I wouldn't figure this out without your help. Thank you, mate!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I noticed (after reading the first answer above), that I had the Keys category selected. I then selected the Certificates category, ensured I did not have any of the available Certificates selected, and I started my request and this time it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Here's the solution (for me at least).

You can have only one developer certificate installed on one machine - delete your old certificate from the keychain and you will be able to create the new one normally.